# spring jms message creation

Tags: spring, jms

If I have assigned a message creator in my listener container which parses out the xml coming out of the queue and creates an equivalent java object for it does, spring jms guarantee this operation is thread safe ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring JMS guarantee that the code calling message creator is thread safe, and it also expect the implementation of message creator to be thread safe too. But whether the overall flow is thread safe or not, really depends on how you write the message creator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends... The Spring `JMSTemplate` is guaranteed to be thread safe as I recall, but the answer really boils to down to your implementation.

Cheers,